# iOS: HTTP service returning <null>, how to test for this?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that relies on a web service that I have no control over. I'm currently trying to solve a bug.

In a particular case, an asynchronous HTTP request returns

```
"<null>"
```

When this happens I get an exception and my app crashes.

I've tried every method I can think of to test for this in an if statement including comparing various strings, arrays, and testing for the characters < and >. Essentially I want to break from a method if the  value is found.

Has anyone run into this before, and how did you solve it?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Some lines of code?
How do you manage the response? What kind of WebService?

Comment: Did you try to make a decision based on the HTTP status code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. It must have helped to write the problem down. I hadn't created an IDENTICAL null object to compare it to yet. My null object actually was generated by a snippet of JSON code, so all i had to do was replicate such an object and use isEqual: to compare them.

Comment: Did you try the above solution?

Comment: Yes, but my null object was a JSON null, not an NSNull

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the below code to test for it

```
if (myObject == [NSNull null]) {
    // handle it
} else {
    // 
 }
```

"The NSNull class defines a singleton object you use to represent null values in situations where nil is prohibited as a value (typically in a collection object such as an array or a dictionary)." - Apple